# How to access a variable in cpp file from another cpp file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a variable of QStringList which has some list in Sql.cpp file but I want to use that list in Edit.cpp. How to do that??

in sql.h:

```
   public:
   QString path;
   static QStringList list;
```

in sql.cpp ->connectDB() function :

```
    void sql::connectDB()
{
QDir dir;
path=ui->dbpath->text();
dir.setPath(path);
 dir.setNameFilters(QStringList()<<"*.db");
list= dir.entryList();
}
```

When I call entryList , the list of filenames storing in list, a QStringList.

edit.cpp:

```
void edit::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
SecDialog s;
s.setModal(true);

qDebug()<< sql::list.at(0);


s.exec();
```

}

i have included sql.h file in edit.cpp file.
But I am getting error " Sql.cpp: error: undefined reference to Sql::list"
in both files where list is used. Hope u get my problem..

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem

Comment: Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of coding randomly. Typical way, would be to declare such a variable in a header file (via the use of `extern`), define it in a single  .cpp file, and include such header wherever you want to use that variable.

Comment: `extern` is not good if QStringList is filled and changed at runtime. Use signals and slots along with `qRegisterMetaType`. If QStringList is const data, never changed I would say `extern` can be used.

Comment: It changes at run time. I have declared it in public as "QStringList list;" in sql.h and used in sql.cpp directly. No problem.Then, I included sql.h file in edit.cpp and used it as " qDebug()<< Sql::list.at(0);" . But it is getting error like invalid use of non-static member.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it as extern in Edit.cpp.

`extern QStringList VarName;`

**update:**
seems like you need to add `QStringList sql::list;` definition to your sql.cpp

Comment: But It is getting error "missing template parameters " where the variable is getting used in SQL.cpp file

Comment: @JaganPJ do you have a `QStringList sql::list;` definition in your sql.cpp?

Comment: @JaganPJ it is a declaration, not a definition. Please, refer http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static to see how to define 
a static class member

Comment: sorry.. It is declaration.By the way, It is working now after adding that declaration you have told.thank you very much for your time